# How to analyse results of vibration isolation test

Tags: vibration

I performed some tests with vibration isolators and have computed the PSD. The natural frequency of the isolators is 110 Hz in the axial direction. So my question is, should I expect to see noise damped below or above 110 Hz? Also should the natural frequency of the system be lower than or higher than the natural frequency of the isolator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not straightforward to answer IMHO. Depending on the mounting and the source of noise you might get different results.

In the most simple case, i.e. if the system can be modelled a sdof system resting on a single isolator, then you'd expect that excitation frequencies higher/greater than the natural frequency would be isolated (in this example 110 Hz). The higher the frequency the higher the isolation.

In that scenario you can see the following graph of transmissibility which shows the transmissibility for different damping ratios.

[image]